# Converting Pojo to query string so I can use in collection.find()

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, bson

**1.How to convert a Pojo to query string that is passed to collection.find(string)?**

I have a Pojo (containing all data except _id) and I want to find corresponding document in mongoDb... So I need a way to query the mongoDB with a Pojo. Anyone aware how to do this?
I'm currently using Jongo library for interacting with mongo.

**2. What should be passed to query string: JSON or BSON or something else?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: query is done based on few fields and not all fields, so maybe you would like to query by certain key fields of the POJO object.

However if you must, you can use Gson library to convert your object to JSON string and us that JSON string to query.

Comment: The idea is to populate fields of a model, and to query with that object (as you stated, will try to convert it to Json) and to get the same object in return but with the _id index field populated... Than the object can be used further...